# Remove word that starts with "(" in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet

I am not used to using Excel. But for a project I want only strings. I am trying to filter data but have many rows and replacing each word is time consuming. I want to remove words in brackets. For Eg: (programming language). In my excel words are in this format python(programming language). Similarly I have many such unique words in the brackets.

Please tell me how can I remove words starting with "(".

I am trying with `Ctrl+H` but I can only replace single word at a time.

Comment: Yes, I am using that but I have to put each word to replace. (programming language), (statistics), (tools), (accounting tool), .... the words go on. I want something which can remove words with brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the replace all box - you can select the sheet, a single row, single column or multiple rows & columns.

[image]

EDIT based on comment:
So, if you put an "*" between the brackets you will replace the whole word including the brackets. If you just put the opening bracket and replace with nothing then the word will be left with the closing bracket, to replace the closing bracket you will need to do it twice - one for the opening and once for cloasing...

[image]

Comment: Please check the image i have posted as an answer I can't replace words with (

Comment: @10sha25 Have edited my answer - use (*) and it works as I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

[this is the error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXAp9.png)